# Maintaining encapsulation with properties and methods

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation

If I have a class as follows:

```
public class Name
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String FullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

FullName() concatenates the first and last names so it makes sense for it to be a method. Suppose I change how the class works so it stores the full name as a string and FirstName and LastName return substrings. It would then  make sense for FirstName and LastName to be methods and FullName to be a property.  I read [these guidelines](http://dipankaronline.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/guidelines-for-when-to-use-properties-vs-methods-from-bill-wagner/) on where to use properties which states that properties should not be interdependent.

Doesn't using properties and methods break encapsulation as it means you are exposing your internal implementation details to external code?

In cases like this where you don't want to expose which values are stored and which are derived what should you do? Presumably they should all be methods or they should all be properties but which?

Comment: why not just make `FullName` a property too with getter only, having fullname and sub stringing for first and last seems like a really bad idea as how will you know where to substring (think about hyphenated names)

Comment: I always thought that this is what [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) were for.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 The guidelines I read [here](http://dipankaronline.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/guidelines-for-when-to-use-properties-vs-methods-from-bill-wagner/) in point 2 states properties should not be interdependent. Is that wrong then?

Comment: they are GUIDE lines not FACT lines

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this doesn't create an interdependency because there would be no setter for the `FullName` property.  Interdependency is when you have a multiple setters that modify the same underlying data.  In the hypothetical example, you can only ever modify one piece of data with a single assignment.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Yes, perhaps we can interpret it as no-interdependency. But on the same page "_They should not have dependencies on each other. Note that this would include setting one property and having it affect another._".

Comment: I'm pretty sure these guideline are subjective, say you have a WPF MVVM application, you would be forced to keep in sync 3 properties, FirstName, LastName and FullName, as you cannot (easily) bind to a method as public properties are the preferred method for the binding engine, if you were to follow these guidelines strictly when a user updated their name you will need to update the First and last name, then the full name, that just seems illogical and risks you data getting out of sync

Comment: @sa_ddam213 You're right, but that's exactly why you should use [multibinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) in those instances and bind directly to both the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties.

Comment: Yes, multibinding is an option but not always feasible especially when bindings and hierarchy get complex, honestly following those guidelines strictly is really up to the developer but in a FirstName, Lastname scenario it seems ridiculous to me, and is quite funny he pointed this out explicitly, no wonder him and John Skeet disagree so much, LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is arguable if properties should or should not be independent.

I would say that in your case, having property

```
public String FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } } // no set
```

looks acceptable.

Compare with .NET [Rectangle.Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.bottom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, which returns sum of two other properties

> The y-coordinate that is the sum of Y and Height of this Rectangle.

Comment: I think the usage of the term "interdependent" is a bit loose here.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer :-) I answered your comment to the question and then read this one. I agree, the term "interdependent" is loose. But see the second point in the page. It seems to address plain dependency.

Comment: I agree.  Although, I find a bit of fault with his guidelines.  A property with no setter is almost *guaranteed* to be dependent upon another; and there's absolutely nothing wrong with that in my opinion.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer I completely agree. Moreover, I even see no fundamental problem with real interdependency (although it may require a bit of accuracy and may add extra using constraints). I would say that it is convenient if properties are orthogonal, but it is not a must at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follows these guidelines strictly then I would create full properties for First and Last name and use a get only accessor on FullName to the private fields, since his guidelines only mention Property dependency not field dependencies.

I assume the guidelines are based on the fact logic can be performed inside getters and setters, going the field route will eliminate that risk

Example:

```
public class Name 
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName 
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return _firstName + " " + _lastName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second item in the guidelines seems to be violated, since setting one property affects another.

Comment: not really, Fullname is not dependant on First or LastName properties, it is on the backing fields though, my assumption is that in some case there could be db logic etc in the setters/getters, ensuring you are only pulling the last set value from the backing fields should cut the dependency on any setter/getter logic if it exists, but if the guidelines intends that you cannot return multiple fields in a property then Microsoft need to learn to follow this persons guidelines if its a problem because its VERY common, IMO if MS does it its more valid than some c# "expert" guidelines.

Comment: I meant that the guidelines say (I do not agree BTW): "_They should not have dependencies on each other. Note that this would include setting one property and having it affect another._" Setting `FirstName` definitely affects `FullName`.

Comment: The way I look at it is FullName is dependant on the values of the fields not the Properties get set logic (which I assume is the point he is trying to convey), I guess it depends on how you interpret these ridiculous guidelines :)